# Kill all pid files in a folder

Tags: bash, unix, command-line, resque, pid

I have a folder that is filled with .pid files.  Each has the PID for a resque worker.  How can I kill every PID in that folder from the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/defunkt/resque#signals) it says to use:

```
ps -e -o pid,command | grep [r]esque-[0-9] | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | xargs -L1 kill -s QUIT
```

**Note**: That looks them up **by name** instead of using the `.pid` files.

Also, the `QUIT` signal will gracefully kill them. If you want to forcefully kill them use `TERM` instead.

Comment: I ended up using the god gem (http://godrb.com/) to control my processes like I should have in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

```
cat folder/*.pid | xargs kill
```

should do it?

If you need to specify a signal, for example `KILL`, then

```
cat folder/*.pid | xargs kill -KILL
```

If your pidfiles lack newlines, this may work better:

```
( cd folder &&
for pidfile in *.pid; do echo kill -QUIT `cat $pidfile`; done
)
```

Comment: You'd probably want to use the `QUIT` signal. According to the [docs](https://github.com/defunkt/resque#signals): "QUIT - Wait for child to finish processing then exit"

Comment: @SamBaumgarten If you use the `TERM` signal, it should forcefully stop all the threads.

Comment: @SamBaumgarten According to the [docs](https://github.com/defunkt/resque#signals) it says to use: `ps -e -o pid,command | grep [r]esque-[0-9] | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | xargs -L1 kill -s QUIT` That looks them up by name instead of using the PIDs.

Comment: @cyfur01 Perfect, that works great. If you post it as a answer I can accept it

Answer (score 2):

Run the command:

```
kill `cat folder/*.pid`
```

If the PID files don't have newlines, then the following should work:

```
for f in folder/*.pid; do kill `cat "$f"`; done
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue with this as I am with @mtndesign's answer. "When I run this I get a string that has all the pids; however there are no spaces. For example, if the pids are 5220 and 5395. It tries to kill a process with the id 52205395"

Answer (score 2):

Run this - with backticks:

```
kill -9 `cat /path/*.pid`
```

Comment: When I run this I get a string that has all the pids; however there are no spaces. For example, if the pids are 5220 and 5395.  It tries to kill a process with the id 52205395

Comment: Probably Not.  I'm just passing it into Resque

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. Can you please try this: `for i in \`ls\`; do kill $i; done`.

Comment: When running for i in ls`; do kill $i; done` I get a prompt to finish the command (a ">").  Removing the -9 didnt help

Comment: The last backtick you used in shell code, should be before the ls. like this: `\`ls\``

Comment: @mtndesign I know this is a tangent (and knit-picky), but using `ls` for a `for` loop is [a bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). @hrunting's loop uses a safer syntax.

Comment: I agree with you @cyfur01 , but it is just a speed suggestion (old habits :)), after hearing that my first answer didn't work, which I couldn't come up with a logical explanation why? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Although the Question is answer but thought that there some many awesome way you can

do some task in linux that what the answer is for exhibiting the power of linux

How abt this

```
pgrep ruby | xargs ps | grep [r]esque | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill -9
```

NOTE: `pgrep` is not supported in MAC-OS just thought would be useful to some one

Answer (score 0):

Leading padding will cause errors. Use`sed 's/^ *//g'` to remove leading spacing/padding:

```
ps -e -o pid,command | grep '[r]esque-[0-9]' | sed 's/^ *//g' | cut -d ' ' -f 1 |  xargs -L1 kill -s QUIT
```

Comment: This is true. If your PIDs loop around and you have PIDs of different length (3 digit vs 4 or 5) the accepted answer will fail and give you all blank PIDs.  This would be hard to detect when it does happen so definitely put that sed replace in there!